# knockout css binding not assigning any class

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am trying to dynamically set a class based on a bool value. 
My markup looks like this:

```
 <input 
   data-bind="
     css: { 
       'chkBxEdit': gThirdCheckboxEnabled(), 
       'chkBx': !gThirdCheckboxEnabled() 
     }, 
     enable: gThirdCheckboxEnabled" />
```

With this code no class is being added, the enable binding is however working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css binding works fine:

```js
var viewmodel = function(){
var self = this;
  this.gThirdCheckboxEnabled = ko.observable(false);
  this.change = function(){
    self.gThirdCheckboxEnabled(!self.gThirdCheckboxEnabled());
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

```css
.chkBxEdit{
  background-color: blue;
}

.chkBx{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="css: { 'chkBxEdit': gThirdCheckboxEnabled(), 'chkBx': !gThirdCheckboxEnabled() }" />



<button data-bind="click: change">Change</button>
```

Comment: this solution does not work in my application.  The observable is getting set from a data source dynamically, which is functional however the css binding is not apply a class attribute

Comment: Above solution looks best possible. Where exactly you are facing problem? What do you mean by 'set from a data source dynamically'?

Comment: I was able to figure it out.  The css binding would have worked if this markup was being rendered traditionally, however due to the way this application is working and where in the flow I had my javascript it was trying to manipulate a string.  In a traditional application this approach would have been correct so I will accept it as the answer. Thanks.